# Elastic BeansTalk: Yum does not have this package available for installation

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, yum

this is 01_packages.config file inside .ebextensions folder

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    postgresql93-devel: []
  commands:
    01_python_devel_install:
      command: 'yum install -y python39-devel'

    02_postgresql_install:
      command: 'yum install -y postgresql93 postgresql93-devel'
```

when i do `eb deploy`

I get error in the logs (cfn-init.txt, to be precise):

```
2023-06-23 00:34:37,835 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2023-06-23 00:34:37,853 [INFO] Running configSets: _OnInstanceBoot
2023-06-23 00:34:37,856 [INFO] Running configSet _OnInstanceBoot
2023-06-23 00:34:37,859 [INFO] Running config AWSEBBaseConfig
2023-06-23 00:34:38,510 [INFO] Command clearbackupfiles succeeded
2023-06-23 00:34:38,514 [INFO] Running config AWSEBCfnHupEndpointOverride
2023-06-23 00:34:38,533 [INFO] Command clearbackupfiles succeeded
2023-06-23 00:34:38,535 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
2023-06-23 00:34:38,535 [INFO] -----------------------Build complete-----------------------
2023-06-23 00:36:16,303 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2023-06-23 00:36:16,309 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2023-06-23 00:36:16,311 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2023-06-23 00:36:16,311 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
2023-06-23 00:36:16,311 [INFO] -----------------------Build complete-----------------------
2023-06-23 00:41:25,793 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2023-06-23 00:41:25,800 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2023-06-23 00:41:25,803 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2023-06-23 00:41:25,805 [INFO] Running config prebuild_0_backend
2023-06-23 00:41:28,430 [ERROR] postgresql93-devel is not available to be installed
2023-06-23 00:41:28,430 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of prebuild_0_backend: Yum does not have postgresql93-devel available for installation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 244, in build
    changes['packages'][manager] = CloudFormationCarpenter._packageTools[manager]().apply(packages,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/rpm_tools.py", line 76, in apply
    raise ToolError("Yum does not have %s available for installation" % pkg_spec)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Yum does not have postgresql93-devel available for installation
2023-06-23 00:41:28,432 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2023-06-23 00:41:28,432 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Yum does not have postgresql93-devel available for installation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 181, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets, strict_mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 137, in build
    Contractor(metadata, strict_mode).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 567, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 244, in build
    changes['packages'][manager] = CloudFormationCarpenter._packageTools[manager]().apply(packages,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/rpm_tools.py", line 76, in apply
    raise ToolError("Yum does not have %s available for installation" % pkg_spec)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Yum does not have postgresql93-devel available for installation
2023-06-23 01:21:13,525 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2023-06-23 01:21:13,531 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2023-06-23 01:21:13,534 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2023-06-23 01:21:13,536 [INFO] Running config prebuild_0_backend
2023-06-23 01:21:15,404 [ERROR] postgresql93-devel is not available to be installed
2023-06-23 01:21:15,404 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of prebuild_0_backend: Yum does not have postgresql93-devel available for installation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 244, in build
    changes['packages'][manager] = CloudFormationCarpenter._packageTools[manager]().apply(packages,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/rpm_tools.py", line 76, in apply
    raise ToolError("Yum does not have %s available for installation" % pkg_spec)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Yum does not have postgresql93-devel available for installation
2023-06-23 01:21:15,405 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2023-06-23 01:21:15,405 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Yum does not have postgresql93-devel available for installation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 181, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets, strict_mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 137, in build
    Contractor(metadata, strict_mode).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 567, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 244, in build
    changes['packages'][manager] = CloudFormationCarpenter._packageTools[manager]().apply(packages,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/rpm_tools.py", line 76, in apply
    raise ToolError("Yum does not have %s available for installation" % pkg_spec)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Yum does not have postgresql93-devel available for installation
2023-06-23 01:29:46,781 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2023-06-23 01:29:46,787 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2023-06-23 01:29:46,790 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2023-06-23 01:29:46,793 [INFO] Running config prebuild_0_backend
2023-06-23 01:29:48,030 [ERROR] amazon-linux-extras is not available to be installed
2023-06-23 01:29:48,030 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of prebuild_0_backend: Yum does not have amazon-linux-extras available for installation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 244, in build
    changes['packages'][manager] = CloudFormationCarpenter._packageTools[manager]().apply(packages,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/rpm_tools.py", line 76, in apply
    raise ToolError("Yum does not have %s available for installation" % pkg_spec)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Yum does not have amazon-linux-extras available for installation
2023-06-23 01:29:48,031 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2023-06-23 01:29:48,031 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Yum does not have amazon-linux-extras available for installation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 181, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets, strict_mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 137, in build
    Contractor(metadata, strict_mode).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 567, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 244, in build
    changes['packages'][manager] = CloudFormationCarpenter._packageTools[manager]().apply(packages,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/rpm_tools.py", line 76, in apply
    raise ToolError("Yum does not have %s available for installation" % pkg_spec)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Yum does not have amazon-linux-extras available for installation
2023-06-23 01:38:39,691 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2023-06-23 01:38:39,698 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2023-06-23 01:38:39,701 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2023-06-23 01:38:39,703 [INFO] Running config prebuild_0_backend
2023-06-23 01:38:40,874 [ERROR] amazon-linux-extras is not available to be installed
2023-06-23 01:38:40,875 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of prebuild_0_backend: Yum does not have amazon-linux-extras available for installation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 244, in build
    changes['packages'][manager] = CloudFormationCarpenter._packageTools[manager]().apply(packages,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/rpm_tools.py", line 76, in apply
    raise ToolError("Yum does not have %s available for installation" % pkg_spec)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Yum does not have amazon-linux-extras available for installation
2023-06-23 01:38:40,875 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2023-06-23 01:38:40,875 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Yum does not have amazon-linux-extras available for installation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 181, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets, strict_mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 137, in build
    Contractor(metadata, strict_mode).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 567, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 244, in build
    changes['packages'][manager] = CloudFormationCarpenter._packageTools[manager]().apply(packages,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/rpm_tools.py", line 76, in apply
    raise ToolError("Yum does not have %s available for installation" % pkg_spec)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Yum does not have amazon-linux-extras available for installation


how do i fix that

ChatGPT
The error message indicates that the postgresql93-devel package is not available for installation in the Yum package manager. This could be due to the package not being found in the package repository or a naming inconsistency.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

Verify the availability of the package: Connect to your AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance via SSH and run the following command to check if the postgresql93-devel package is available in the repository:

sql
Copy code
sudo yum search postgresql93-devel
If the package is not found, it might indicate that it is not available in the default repository or the package name might be different. In that case, you will need to find the correct package name or add a repository that provides the package.

Use a different package: If postgresql93-devel is not essential for your application, you can try using a different package or remove it from the 01_packages.config file. This way, the deployment process won't fail due to the missing package.

Update package names or repository: If the package is available in a different repository or with a different name, you can modify the .ebextensions/01_packages.config file accordingly. Ensure that the package name and repository are accurate.

For example, if the package is available in the postgresql-devel package or a different repository, you can modify the file as follows:

yaml
Copy code
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    postgresql-devel: []  # Modified package name

commands:
  01_python_devel_install:
    command: 'yum install -y python39-devel'

  02_postgresql_install:
    command: 'yum install -y postgresql postgresql-devel'  # Modified package name
Save the changes and redeploy your application using eb deploy.

Custom AMI or Docker container: If the above steps don't work, you can consider creating a custom AMI or using a Docker container to ensure the required dependencies are pre-installed in your environment. This will provide more control over the software stack and allow you to install specific packages as needed.

Remember to test your deployment changes in a non-production environment before applying them to your live application.
```

I am trying to deploy a django application by the way.